# Select First table data and pass it to int value and print it in second table? ERRORS

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I want to select `id` from one table and insert that `id` to another table. 
First I need to read my first table id and want to pass it to string.
Then I need to pass that string to second table.

```
String selQuery = "SELECT Id FROM MapDataImage WHERE Source='" + TextBox1.Text + "';";
{
    int MId = int.TryParse(Id);
    String QueryStr = "INSERT INTO User_Images VALUES (@Image)";
    SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand(QueryStr, conn);
    SqlDataReader sqldread = scmd.ExecuteReader();

    //String QueryStr = "UPDATE MapDataImage SET Image = @Image WHERE Source='" + TextBox1.Text + "';";
    //SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand(QueryStr, conn);
    scmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = imgbytes;
    scmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

so is this correct?

```
int MId = int.TryParse(Id); //the name id does not exist in current context?
```

but i want to retrieve particular id value from database

or

```
int MId = int.TryParse(@Id);
```

Comment: `Tryparse` returns a boolean value not integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
int MId = int.Parse("Id");
```

Will never work. `"Id"` is a string literal, it can never be an integer. I think you need to specify a variable

```
int mId = int.Parse(id);
```

Aside that, try using `TryParse` so it's safer.

Also use `paramerterised queries` on your `SELECT` statement to prevent `SQL Injection`.

Please post the rest of your code and I will adjust my answer to accomodate.

Answer (score 0):

You don't create DataReaders objects by yourself. Instead you obtain a reference to DataReader object by invoking ExecuteReader method of Command class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader.aspx